# Can performance be improved by breaking databases up?

Tags: sql-server, performance, recursive, performance-tuning

Performance is my over-riding concern, as I have a heavily recursive CTE that is the engine room of my application. This CTE may have to work on 4 columns of up to 7 million rows. Queries can take over 30 minutes with just 1.2 million rows.

To reduce the waiting time of most users, I save minimalist 2 column tables that capture the results of long-running CTE recursion queries into a separate "cache" database. Thus 1000s of these two column tables, some containing nearly 7 million rows collect in this database

Since both databases are dealing with subsets of the same basic records, I am wondering how best to store all 8-10 columns for each record so that the data is available to efficiently join with results from either database. I have to maintain concurrency with the base data in the CTE specific database as new records are added. At the moment I keep and upkeep the same data in both databases.

Is there a better way to do all of this? Should I just keep all the data in one database? If so, how will my long-running CTEs interact with lots of interruptions, and won't all users then have to wait more, as I suspect?

Recursive CTE:

```
USE [relationship]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [home].[proportion]    Script Date:     2/24/2016 9:51:22 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

-- =============================================
-- Author: Me
-- Create date: today
-- Description: cte with normalized tbls
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [home].[proportion] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @id int
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    DELETE FROM relationship.home.persistedTemp WHERE originator = @id;
    WITH PctCTE(id, percent, kind)
    AS
        (SELECT individual, CONVERT(DECIMAL(28,25),100.0) AS percent, model
            FROM relationship.home.relationshipRecords constituent
            WHERE constituent.individual = @id
        UNION ALL
            SELECT derivation.individual, CONVERT(DECIMAL(28,25),constituent.percent/2.0), derivation.model
            FROM relationship.home.relationshipRecords AS derivation
            INNER JOIN PctCTE AS constituent
            ON (constituent.kind = 'M' AND
        (derivation.inputKindB = constituent.id))
            OR
            (NOT constituent.kind = 'M' AND
            (derivation.inputKindA = constituent.id))
        ),
        mergeCTE(i, p)
        AS
            (SELECT id, SUM(percent)
            FROM PctCTE
            GROUP BY id
            )
            INSERT INTO relationship.home.persistedTemp
            SELECT @id, tmp.i, tmp.p, w.yr
            FROM mergeCTE AS tmp
            LEFT JOIN relationship.home.beginning w
            ON tmp.i = w.individual;
    DELETE FROM relationship.home.persistedTemp WHERE originator = @id AND i = @id

END
```

Note: inputKindA may be used to create many individuals (1000s), inputKindB may be used to create less individuals (up to 20), and both often create no individuals.

The database associated with the CTE is called *relationship* and contains the following tables:

**myids**

```
record_id                   char(6)                     PK FK
reg                         nchar(10)                   PK
name                        nvarchar(60)    
individual                  int                         FK U1
main                        int

FK_myids_names
IX_myids_1                  individual(ASC)             Unique
PK_myids                    record_id (ASC), reg (ASC)  Unique  Clustered
```

**names**

```
individual                  int                         PK {I}
name                        nvarchar(60)

PK_names                    individual (ASC)            Unique  Clustered
```

**relationshipRecords**

```
individual                  int                         FK
inputKindA                  int                         {I}
inputKindB                  int                         I2
model                       char(1)                     I3

FK_relationshipRecords_names
IX_relationshipRecords_B    inputKindB (ASC)
IX_relationshipRecords_mdl  model (ASC)
IX_relationshipRecords_id   individual (ASC)            Unique
IX_relationshipRecords_A    inputKindA (ASC)                    Clustered
```

**beginning**

```
individual                  int                         FK
yr                          smallint                    {I}
color                       nvarchar(50)    

FK_beginning_names
IX_beginning_culr           color (ASC)
IX_beginning_id             individual (ASC)            Unique
IX_beginning_yr             yr (ASC)                            Clustered
```

**persistedTemp**

```
originator                  int     
i                           int     
p                           decimal(28,25)  
y                           smallint

IX_persistedTemp            originator (ASC)                    Clustered
```

and **record_log**

```
record_id                   char(6)                     PK
version_id                  char(3)     
cntry_id                    char(2) 
record_nm                   nvarchar(255)   
notes                       nvarchar(max)   
updtd                       int     
base_yr                     smallint        
user_id                     nvarchar(255)   
dflt_id                     char(15)    
dflt_nm                     nvarchar(255)   
css_ref                     nvarchar(255)   
url_ref                     nvarchar(255)   
bt_link                     nvarchar(150)   

PK_record_log               record_id (ASC)             Unique  Clustered
```

Finally, the database that stores the cached long-query results has the following tables:

**hinfo**, which holds redundant data from the **names**, **relationshipRecords**, and **beginning** tables above:

```
individual                  int                         PK U1
reg                         nvarchar(255)   
name                        nvarchar(60)                U1
kinds                       nvarchar(121)   
year                        smallint                    {I}
color                       nvarchar(50)    
model                       char(1)         

PK_hinfo                    individual (ASC)            Unique
IX_hinfo                    year (ASC)                          Clustered
IX_nameorder                individual (ASC), name (ASC)    Unique
```

**srch_log**

```
individual                  int                         PK FK
last_id                     int     
last_dt                     datetime2(7)    
hit_cnt                     int     
lapse                       int     
saved                       bit     

PK_srch_log                 individual (ASC)            Unique  Clustered
```

and mostly this database stores many of the following type of tables:

**p000001**

```
i                           int                         PK
p                           decimal(28,25)              I1
PK_p000001                  i (ASC)                     Unique
IX_p000001                  p (ASC)                             Clustered
```

Clearly, the caching is a major pain, especially since they must often be updated when new individuals are added to the records. Ideally, the CTE would just run a whole lot faster.

Comment: Separating the tables into different databases will have minimal benefit, especially if they are ending up almost identical in what data is being stored. The number of rows you're referencing is substantial enough to start seeing issues but not enough to be a definitive problem, but there is some potential that your CTE is poorly optimized. I assume you're using the recursive aspect of it? Also if you're creating thousands of small breadth but very deep tables that may be causing issues too. It's possible some query, table, and index redesign may fix your problems, but we would need more info.

Comment: I guess I am applying some of my queueing theory background in thinking that I can in essence "add an express line" and thus reduce average wait times overall. I hope that adding the CTE code, and some of the database structure, to this question can help your analysis of my situation.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer but this part:

```
WITH PctCTE(id, percent, kind, count)
    AS
        ( ... ),
    mergeCTE(dups, i, p)
    AS
        (SELECT ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY count) 'dups',
                id, SUM(percent) OVER (PARTITION BY id)
        FROM PctCTE
        )
INSERT INTO 
    relationship.home.persistedTemp
SELECT @id, tmp.i, tmp.p, when.yr
FROM mergeCTE AS tmp
  LEFT JOIN relationship.home.beginning when
  ON tmp.i = when.individual
WHERE dups = 1;
```

can be simplified to:

```
WITH PctCTE (id, percent, kind, count)
    AS
        ( ... ),
    mergeCTE (i, p)
    AS
        (SELECT id, SUM(percent)
         FROM PctCTE
         GROUP BY id
        )
INSERT INTO 
    relationship.home.persistedTemp
SELECT @id, tmp.i, tmp.p, w.yr
FROM mergeCTE AS tmp
  LEFT JOIN relationship.home.beginning AS w
  ON tmp.i = w.individual ;
```

If that's correct and I'm not missing something, then the recursive `PctCTE` can also be simplified. The `count` column seems to be used no where at all.

Comment: **Good advice!** Thank you. I implemented your suggested simplification and took about 20% off of the time it took to run an iteration against this stored procedure that returned 124389 rows, going from 2 min 27 sec to 1 min 57 sec. The only difference in the output was that it wasn't sorted by i. The sorting is much quicker to do elsewhere in the process.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you might try using a recursive CTE with multiple recursive members rather than that awkward OR join syntax.  Might enable use of that index on InputKindB you have.  Could you post the execution plan?

```
WITH PctCTE(id, percent, kind)
    AS
        (
        SELECT individual, CONVERT(DECIMAL(28,25),100.0) AS percent, model
            FROM relationship.home.relationshipRecords constituent
            WHERE constituent.individual = @id
        UNION ALL
            SELECT derivation.individual, CONVERT(DECIMAL(28,25),constituent.percent/2.0), derivation.model
            FROM relationship.home.relationshipRecords AS derivation
            INNER JOIN PctCTE AS constituent ON constituent.id = derivation.inputKindB
            WHERE constituent.kind = 'M'
        UNION ALL
            SELECT derivation.individual, CONVERT(DECIMAL(28,25),constituent.percent/2.0), derivation.model
            FROM relationship.home.relationshipRecords AS derivation
            INNER JOIN PctCTE AS constituent ON constituent.id = derivation.inputKindA
            WHERE NOT(constituent.kind = 'M')
        )
```